# How do I set multiple custom templates for the Shop page in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I would like to let the user choose between different templates, such as full with or content with sidebar for the Shop page, but the problem is that the shop page always uses the archive-product.php template.

Thank you

Comment: I'd probably add a `$_GET` variable to the end of the shop link `/shop?layout=full` and then use that to load different templates.

Answer (score 0):

Make a regular (not shop) page and add this shortcode:

```
[products orderby="menu_order"]
```

Other options to customize are available here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

To make your different templates, just make custom page templates as you would for any page:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

...And then select the template from the Page Attributes menu for that page, typically on the right about half way down.  Now you can set up different shop pages with different text and layouts, and the savvy client can change between the templates you build.

Also note, when you use the shortcode above for a custom shop page, you can put in-page CSS.  Just wrap it in `<style</style>` tags, though many frown on that practice.